# I don't want my wordpress page to be seen publicly yet

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to trying Wordpress development.  I'm using wordpress.com directly to develop my first site.  I'd rather not have to use FTP or anything more than just their website to continue this development.

I'd like the page to not be online until I'm ready for it to go public.  How do I "turn off" the page - in other words, can I disable it so that only I can see it?  Thanks!

Comment: Found this on google. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-want-to-disable-my-live-site-while-i-work-on-it

Comment: There are a number of plugins that display a custom "coming soon" message to the public but the whole site for a logged in administrator. Try this one - https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/

Comment: Cool, ok, so the solution is the plugin.  Thank you both!

Comment: You say you're using WordPress.com - yet the comments are suitable for WordPress.org. They are different, but seem to have solved your issue? See http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/ and if you need further help clarify which one you are using.

Comment: @ Mark, yes, that is true.  I am using wordpress.com, so I don't think plugins will work.  Although that being considered, I'll probably have to start using my own domain so I can use plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coming soon plugin to your site that prevents user to view pages of your site.

But when you login to your admin, you can see all those pages. So that you can continue your development.

There are numerous plugins which adds coming soon or landing page to non logged in user and shows page content to administrator.

You can try this plugin: [Ultimate Coming Soon Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set page not publicly you can set particular Page as a Draft from the sidebar there is a button **Save Draft**

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you develop on your local PC. it will give you full control and once done you can move this site to your online site.

this may help you.

[Installing WordPress Locally](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Installation_Techniques#Installing_WordPress_Locally)